# Problem with unrouted net constraint in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I'm designing a PCB with Altium 17.1 and I routed all the tracks but the DRC says there is an unrouted via. The mentioned via is connected to +5V and it is indeed routed so I'm confused. I attached a screenshot of my design. I shelved the the two ground polygons so you can see the components better. Is there anyone who had the same problem? What's the workaround?

[image]

Comment: No workaround.  You need to figure out which piece of copper doesn't have the right connection.  Right-click on the tracks around it and bring up 'properties'... ensure the net name given is correct for each piece of copper.  Failing that, sometimes (often maybe) you get an orpaned piece of copper that's smaller than the via.  Do a 'click-hold-drag-release' to select everything nearby and look for anything that shouldn't be there.

Comment: As is customary with Altium, when encountering difficulty, delete all nearby offenders, restart the software, and then replace the missing bits again.  This routine usually works universally within the Altium ecosystem for both PCB and SCH.  It's hard to tell from the low resolution picture, but also ensure that the offending via is not intersecting a split-plane boundary, as that can cause problems as well.  Maybe a double-hit via (2 via's very close to, or exactly on top of each other).  With Altium the possibilities are endless!  _Feet on table._

Comment: "DRC says there is an unrouted via" - please, always state the exact error. And show a meaningful screenshot of the affected area (and only this area).

Answer (score 0):

I opened the design with Altium 21 and the DRC error was gone! I'm guessing it was a bug in Altium 17. thanks for your answers.